# Assert # of values in an Array

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

This is my response array.

```
"IDValues": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
    },
    {
      "Id": 4,
    },
    {
      "Id": 5,
    },
]
```

I have used JSON Extractor and Debug Sampler to find the count of Id's in the array. Got the answer as 5.

Now I have to assert the count value as 5. To keep it as a validation point.

I have tried using XPath extractor and Regular Expression Extractor, but all I was able to do is to extract the value but not assert it. How can this be accomplished? Which post processor should be used ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and configure it as follows:

   [image]
2. It will produce the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

   ```
   IDValues_1={"Id":1}
   IDValues_2={"Id":2}
   IDValues_3={"Id":3}
   IDValues_4={"Id":4}
   IDValues_5={"Id":5}
   IDValues_matchNr=5
   ```
3. Now you can use [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to verify if `IDValues_matchNr` variable value is equal to `5`, the relevant configuration would be

   [image]

Comment: What is the expression to get the first ID value in the Json extractor? 
Is it $.IDValues.Id[0]? Can i use the variable in the body data of the next request? like ${IDValues1} or something like that